# xdebug gives Fatal error: Class not found

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I've setup the xdebug, and I think I have installed it correctly. When I run php -v in terminal, it showed up my "with xDebug v2.6.1". Looking at the phpinfo(), it does show the xdebug extension. Running php -m on terminal does show the Xdebug under the [Zend Modules].

Now I'm trying to set it up for VS Code. I have the extension PHP Debug installed, Chrome extension xdebug installed.

The problem now is when I F5 from VS Code, it will give me fatal error : Class 'ParentClass' not found.

I'm running PHP v7.0.30 for Windows 10, with the server being IIS.

My php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_log = "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP\v7.0\tmp\xdebug.log"
zend_extension = "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP\v7.0\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.0-vc14-nts.dll"
```

Any idea?

Comment: You have a stack trace?

Comment: None. Nothing get printed on xdebug.log too.

Comment: And it runs when xdebug is not enabled?

Comment: Make sure that your vscode is configured to run your project from your index.php that runs your autoloader if you are using one...